# Drawing a not-growing circle with falling itensity

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I would like to draw a circle with falling itensity to the outer bounderies.

Now I have implemented a solution, but the circle is looping drawing a growing circle. Is it possible to implement a circle without this growing?

I think I should change only the color and use it without any loop, is this right?

Now my code looks like this:

```
        for j in range(1, DIAGONAL_SCREEN):
        intensity = ((DIAGONAL_SCREEN-j)/DIAGONAL_SCREEN)
        circle_loc = plt.Circle(Raspi_Coords[ip], j, color=CIRCLE_COLOR_FALLING_INTENSITY, alpha=intensity, fill=1)
        ax1.add_artist(circle_loc)
        fig1.canvas.draw()
        circle_loc.remove()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a sequential colormap instead of the color?

Comment: Anyone an idea? Should I do this with with plt.scatter?